# Unable to send mail from bitmani google cloud LAMP stack

Tags: php, sendmail, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

Am new to Bitnami, using google cloud platform
I have configured the domain and also uploaded the code which looks fine.
When am trying to send the mail, Mail is not being send can anyone help me please.

I have used zf2 
change the bitnami mail port to 465 
Following is the code I have been using in my mail function

```
$to = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$from = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$body = 'test body';
$subject = 'test subject';
$text = new \Zend\Mime\Part($message);
$text->type = \Zend\Mime\Mime::TYPE_HTML;
$text->charset = 'utf-8';
$body = new \Zend\Mime\Message();
$body->setParts(array($text));
$message = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
$message->setBody($body);
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->addTo($to);
$message->setSubject($subject);
$transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
if($transport->send($message)){
    return true ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/

Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587. By default, these outbound SMTP ports are blocked because of the large amount of abuse these ports are susceptible to.

Although standard email ports are blocked, you can choose a non-standard port to send email through. You can also take advantage of the mail services offered by Compute Engine partners.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform doesn't allow SMTP traffic through default ports: 25, 465, 587 so you need to use another one. You have more information on how to configure email settings using GCP here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#how-to-configure-your-application-to-use-a-third-party-smtp-service-for-outgoing-email

Example alternatives are: Sendgrid or Mandrill